# Как создать symlink или ярлык в windows с помощью python в смонтированной папке

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu

Есть Убунту, у которой есть смонтированный диск /mnt/disk.
Этот disk - находится в среде windows и смонтирован с использованием протокола SMB.
Нужно делать ярлыки на папки с помощью скрипта, который запускается на Убунту таким образом, что бы они в windows нормально работали.
Пробовал так: os.symlink(src, dst). Но получаю ошибку: [Errno 95] Operation not supported
Если бы можно было ссылку (ярлык) создать как текстовый файл, то проблемы бы небыло.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас диск смонтирован как `drvfs`, я полагаю. Драйвер `drvfs` не умеет создавать символические ссылки на SMB дисках.

Вам нужно монтировать диск как `cifs` с опцией `mfsymlinks`:

```bash
sudo mount -t cifs -o 'username=user,password=pwd,uid=1000,gid=1000,mfsymlinks' '//server/share' /mnt/disk
```

Здесь `username` и `password` - это логин и пароль пользователя на машине `server`

Ссылка создаётся как файл в формате [*Minshall+French*](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/UNIX_Extensions#Minshall.2BFrench_symlinks)

Формат - это техническая подробность. Для программ, работающих в WSL, MF-ссылки работают в точности как символические ссылки в Linux/Unix - их можно создавать, можно делать `stat`, можно разыменовывать.

В частности, `os.symlink` успешно создаёт ссылки.

Пример. Я смонтировал удалённую шару как `cifs` в каталог `/mnt/w/`

Создаю ссылку в `python`

```bash
python -c 'import os; os.symlink("/mnt/w/wget-log", "/mnt/w/zzz/some.txt")'
```

Проверяю ссылку `ls -l /mnt/w/zzz/some.txt`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 15 Nov 15 18:49 /mnt/w/zzz/some.txt -> /mnt/w/wget-log
```

Печатаю содержимое файла по ссылке `cat /mnt/w/zzz/some.txt`

```
--2023-09-28 19:00:58--  https://...
bla-bla-bla
```

Ограничение: ссылка работает только в пределах шары. То есть внутри `/mnt/w` работает ссылка на `/mnt/w/some_stuff`, но не работает ссылка на `/mnt/c/some_stuff`

Comment: Хорошо, когда я смонтирую диск таким образом, как затем symlink сделать?

Comment: `os.symlink` работает, скрипты в WSL видят эти файлы именно как символические ссылки и успешно октрывают файлы, на которые указывает ссылки

Comment: я смонтировал диск с опцией mfsymlinks, и действительно по команде os.symlink(src, '/блабла/l.txt') создан файлик l.txt. И как текстовый он содержит вот это - 
XSym
0069
108b8edc04e0438ae83d5e39c2467741
/mnt/designers/Исходники

Но он не работает как ссылка в среде WINDOWS

Comment: Конечно не работает. Это симлинки для WSL. В нативной винде symlink поддерживается на уровне NTFS, они не работают в удалённых дисках. Максимум вы можете сделать ярлыки. Но я не уверен, что ярлыки будут нормально обрабатываться чем-то помимо проводника. Если всё-таки вам нужны ярлыки, то их создать можно скриптом [mslink](https://www.mamachine.org/mslink/mslink_v1.3.sh)

Comment: Спасибо и на том, задача была как раз получить работающий ярлык в винде :)